# jQuery: write html symbols in SVG tspan

Tags: jquery, svg, tspan

I'm trying to write HTML symbols (like `&deg;`) in a TSPAN element with jQuery.
In a simple SPAN it's easy:

```
$('#span_id').html('&deg;');
```

With the TSPAN this way doesn't work, if I use

```
$('#tspan_id').html('&deg;');
```

nothing is printed out.

With

```
$('#tspan_id').text('&deg;');
```

`&deg;` is printed  instead of `°` (obviously)

[Look at the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxMarkson/ENBqz/)

How can I do?

Comment: `$('#tspan_id').html('&deg;');` works well for me. Firefox 22

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8upc9hD.png

Comment: Did you try with chrome? I need to use that browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.append()` function for this

```
$('#tspan_id').empty().append('&deg;');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/ENBqz/1/)

Comment: +1 for some reason that works! I'm guessing it's calling createTextNode and appendChild internally?

Comment: @adeneo it seems so. In many cases `append` will work differently than `.html()`

Answer (score 1):

SVG Nodes don't have a innerHTML property as they are not HTML, and that means they can't be set with jQuery's `html()` method.

Using entities is therefore out of the question, but you can convert them before inserting them:

```
var txt = $('<div />').html('&deg;').text();
$('#tspan_id').text(txt);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ENBqz/2/)

Comment: I've tried it, your answer is correct but isn't the shortest one...thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @MaxMarkson - changed the fiddle link, must have forgotton to save?

Comment: Thank you, but I think the Spokey's answer is more usefull for me.

Comment: @MaxMarkson - no problem, Spokey's answer is simpler and works fine.